# How to pause redis slave to update from master temporarily?

Tags: redis

I would like to make a query (multiple calls) that requires snapshot isolation (No updates). Is there a way to pause a slave from updating itself from master temporarily so that I can run the query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SLAVEOF NO ONE` command to turn off the replication. When you're done with the snapshot, use the `SLAVEOF master-host master-port` to re-sync from the master.

Comment: Is very expensive. It will discard old data and load new data.

Comment: How about sending the `SAVE` command to slave to get a snapshot of RDB file, and reload it by another Redis instance.